# ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row while displaying the output

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery

I want to display 3 output with some condition for that particular output only not for entire query. so I used the sub-query in select statement.

I tried below code

```
--CREATE TABLE i86813_dt190429 as 
                   SELECT 
                   /*+ use_hash(RAP01 RAA02 RAP06) */ 
                   DISTINCT 'I86813' AS audit_id,
                   rap01.plcy                 AS plcy,
                   rap01.stuscd,
                   raa02.enddt_t              AS enddt,
                   rap01.j01_pt_line_cat_cd   AS j01_pt_line_cat_cd,
                   rap01.j01_pt_cdb_part_id   AS j01_pt_cdb_part_id,
                   rap01.j01_pt_state_cd      AS j01_pt_state_cd,
                   rap06.sctype,
                   raa02.EACPRC,

                   (SELECT rap06.pstsc
                     FROM rap06
                     JOIN raa02
                   ON rap06.plcy = raa02.plcy
                      AND raa02.enddt_t - 1 BETWEEN rap06.enddt_t AND ( rap06.dropdt_t - 1 )
                   ) AS pstsc_before_ea  --one day before EA
                   ,
                   (
                   SELECT rap01.aap
                     FROM rap01
                     JOIN raa02
                   ON rap01.plcy = raa02.plcy
                      AND raa02.enddt_t - 1 = rap01.enddt_t
                   ) AS aap_before_ea        --one day before EA and after EA
                   ,
                   (
                   SELECT rap01.aap
                     FROM rap01
                     JOIN raa02
                   ON rap01.plcy = raa02.plcy
                      AND raa02.enddt_t > rap01.enddt_t
                   ) AS aap_after_ea
--
from RAP01
--
Join RAA02 
ON raa02.j46_pt_line_cat_cd    = rap01.j01_pt_line_cat_cd
AND raa02.j46_pt_cdb_part_id   = rap01.j01_pt_cdb_part_id
AND raa02.j46_pt_state_cd      = rap01.j01_pt_state_cd
AND raa02.plcy                 = rap01.plcy
AND raa02.EACPRC               = '25'                    --channel of processing.
AND raa02.ahevnt               = '0993'                  -- ??
and raa02.sprodt_t             BETWEEN '13-AUG-2018' and '14-APR-2019'
--
left JOIN RAP06
ON RAP06.J42_PT_LINE_CAT_CD    = RAP01.J01_PT_LINE_CAT_CD
AND RAP06.J42_PT_CDB_PART_ID   = RAP01.J01_PT_CDB_PART_ID
AND RAP06.J42_PT_STATE_CD      = RAP01.J01_PT_STATE_CD
AND RAP06.PLCY                 = RAP01.PLCY
AND RAP06.SCTYPE               = '085'
AND RAA02.enddt_t              BETWEEN RAP06.ENDDT_T AND  (RAP06.DROPDT_T  - 1)     
--
WHERE rap01.j01_pt_line_cat_cd = 'A'
AND rap01.co3 || rap01.line3 IN (
'065010',
'010010',
'027010',
'021010',
'386010',
'065019',
'010019',
'027019',
'021019',
'386019'
)
AND RAP06.PLCY is NULL;
```

I got error as 'ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row'
and '01427. 00000 -  "single-row subquery returns more than one row"'

Could you please suggest the solution.

Comment: If you are using subquery  in main select then it should return single value.

Comment: test Group by and don't use distinct for this query...

Comment: *"test Group by and don't use distinct for this query... "* Yuk `GROUP BY` suggestion for data unduplication and without using aggregate functions, but i guess its a matter of taste.. Also topicstarter i advice you to read [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query) for providing example data and expected results if you want better comments and or answers.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using subquery  in main select then it should return single value.  Looks like you are passing the date range filter which is retuning multiple rows.

```
AND raa02.enddt_t - 1 BETWEEN rap06.enddt_t AND ( rap06.dropdt_t - 1 )
```

You can join these subqueries as derived table to the base table.

Answer (score 0):

In your select statement you have 3 subqueries to populate the columns `pstsc_before_ea`, `aap_before_ea` and `aap_after_ea`:

```
.....
                   (SELECT rap06.pstsc
                     FROM rap06
                     JOIN raa02
                   ON rap06.plcy = raa02.plcy
                      AND raa02.enddt_t - 1 BETWEEN rap06.enddt_t AND ( rap06.dropdt_t - 1 )
                   ) AS pstsc_before_ea  --one day before EA
                   ,
                   (
                   SELECT rap01.aap
                     FROM rap01
                     JOIN raa02
                   ON rap01.plcy = raa02.plcy
                      AND raa02.enddt_t - 1 = rap01.enddt_t
                   ) AS aap_before_ea        --one day before EA and after EA
                   ,
                   (
                   SELECT rap01.aap
                     FROM rap01
                     JOIN raa02
                   ON rap01.plcy = raa02.plcy
                      AND raa02.enddt_t > rap01.enddt_t
                   ) AS aap_after_ea
```

each of them should return **only 1 row**. 
But it looks like at least 1 of them is returning more.
You can avoid the error by using something like:

```
SELECT max(rap01.aap)...
```

if this suits your logic.

Comment: I can't use any aggregate function in my logic. So this will not work.